# 403 Forbidden error Mule using http outbound endpoint

Tags: rss, mule, mule-studio

I am trying to poll an RSS feed using Mule Studio but have been unsuccessful polling the information using the http outbound-endpoint in the Mule application. I have previously encountered the same issue using the http inbound-endpoint with the same site but was able to resolve the issue by assigning the User-Agent to MuleESB by setting the address to be

```
http://www.theaggie.org/feed/?User-Agent=MuleESB
```

However, now with the http outbound-endpoint, I am unable to poll the feed and get a 403 Forbidden error. My XML for the flow is

```
    <flow name="aggregatorFlow1" doc:name="aggregatorFlow1">
        <poll>
            <processor-chain>
                 <set-variable variableName="httpMessages" value="#[[]]" />
                 <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" address="http://www.theaggie.org/feed/?User-Agent=MuleESB" method="GET" />
                 <expression-component>httpMessages.add(message.payloadAs(java.lang.String))</expression-component>
            </processor-chain>
        </poll>
        <logger level="INFO" message="#[httpMessages]" />
    </flow>
```

If I change the exchange-pattern to request-response, the logger would just output [ ]. I do not have issues with other sites using the same xml code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the `exchange-pattern` should be `request-response`, as you seem to care about the payload of the response.

Try adding the following before the `http:outbound-endpoint`:

```
<set-property propertyName="User-Agent" value="MuleESB" />
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you! How come doing this would work but it wouldn't work if I set the user-agent to MuleESB within the url?

Comment: Outbound endpoints have access to the current message properties, which don't exist for inbound endpoints. This is why with the inbound endpoint you had to use a URL param.